# d3 - foreign object - getting the right scope

Tags: object, d3.js, scope

I am using `foreignObject` to use HTML inside a d3 circle.

What I want:

- use HTML inside d3 objects
- reach the normal scopes outside of HTML code

Now I have problems to get the right scope for using functions. 
If I use "this" inside the

> .html(".....")

I get the "g" element of d3. So is there a way to get to my normal scopes? 
 Or is there even a more elegant way to solve this problem?

```
var foreign = that._foreignObject = d3.select(this).append("foreignObject")
 .attr("width", 30)
 .attr("height", 30)
 .append("xhtml:div")
 .style("font", "15px 'Arial'")
 .html("<button name=Klickmich type=button value=play onclick=>");
```

**EDIT: 16.12.2013**:

```
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })

                //click once
                .on("click", function (d) {


                if (that._foreignObject) {
                    that._foreignObject.remove();
                }



                    that.toggle(d);
                    that.update(d);
                    that.onNodeClick(d);


                    var circle = d3.select(this).select("circle")
                        .transition() 
                        .duration(750)
                        .attr("r", 17)
                        .attr("width", 40)
                        .attr("heigth", 40)
                        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("5,2"))
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("stroke", "black");



                     var button = "<button name=Klickmich type=button value=play onclick=>";
                    var foreign = that._foreignObject = d3.select(this).append("foreignObject")
                        .attr("width", 30)
                        .attr("height", 30)
                        .append("xhtml:div")
                        .style("font", "15px 'Arial'")
                        .html(button)

                    .on("click", function (d) {
                        console.log("heyho");

                        });


                    d3.select(this).select("text").transition() 
                        .duration(750)
                        .style("font-size", 15)
                        .style("font-weight", "bold")
                        .attr("x", function (d) {
                            return d.children || d._children ? -20 : -20;
                        });



                })
```

Comment: What do you mean by normal scope? What do you want `this` to be?

Comment: Object {srcNodeRef: null, _connects: Array[0], _supportingWidgets: Array[0], params: Object, d3: Object…}

Comment: ah i got it myself. just used on click on the xhtml:div

Comment: i have one more problem i cant fix. If i click the xhtml:div it triggers my onclick for the node too. i will paste a piece of sourcecode in my main post to make it more clear

Comment: So you want separate click handlers for the `g` and the contained `div`?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? It sounds like you wouldn't be able to trigger one without the other?

Comment: did it on my own just by jusing a variable and an if check

Comment: Great. Would you mind posting this as an answer for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i Click on my html button i set

```
this._clicked = 1;
```

And the onClick function of the node is build as follows:

```
.on("click", function (d) {
   if (this._clicked == null) {  

    // some code

    }
}

 this._clicked = null;
```